# phpで取得したDBの値をchart.jsのデータに使用したい

Tags: javascript, php, json, chart.js

はじめまして。
javascriptの初心者なのですが、グラフを比較的容易に描画できるライブラリとしてchart.jsを見つけ、簡単なサンプルを作ってみました。
実践的に使用する場合、DB上に格納されている値を、グラフの値にセットすることが必須要件になると思うのですが、phpで取得した配列の値をchart.jsに渡す方法が良く判りません。
検索すると、ajaxというキーワードが出てくるのですが、ページを開いた時に表示されるだけの処理であれば、

```
<?php
$js_ary = json_encode($db_ary);
?>
<script type = "text/javascript">
<!--
    var ary = JSON.parse('<?php echo $js_ary; ?>');
    (以下省略)
```

というように、JSON形式でデータを渡して、処理をするだけでよいのでしょうか？

素人丸出しの質問で申し訳ないですが、よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

> JSON形式でデータを渡して、処理をするだけでよいのでしょうか？

JSONでなくても　configの`'data: [0,0,0,0,0],'`などの行を`echo`などで出力すれば表示できます。
また、以下にJSONデータ（固定データ）から表示する様に表示サンプルを直してみました。

```js
var randomScalingFactor = function() {
   return Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
  };

  var config = {
   type: 'pie',
   data: {
    datasets: [{
     data: [0,0,0,0,0],
     backgroundColor: [
      window.chartColors.red,
      window.chartColors.orange,
      window.chartColors.yellow,
      window.chartColors.green,
      window.chartColors.blue,
     ],
     label: 'Dataset 1'
    }],
    labels: [
     'Red',
     'Orange',
     'Yellow',
     'Green',
     'Blue'
    ]
   },
   options: {
    responsive: true
   }
  };

  window.onload = function() {
   var ctx = document.getElementById('chart-area').getContext('2d');
   window.myPie = new Chart(ctx, config);
            var jsondata = JSON.parse('{"A":12,"B":20,"C":25,"D":21,"E":22}');
            config.data.datasets[0].data[0] = jsondata["A"];
            config.data.datasets[0].data[1] = jsondata["B"];
            config.data.datasets[0].data[2] = jsondata["C"];
            config.data.datasets[0].data[3] = jsondata["D"];
            config.data.datasets[0].data[4] = jsondata["E"];
            window.myPie.update();
        };

  document.getElementById('randomizeData').addEventListener('click', function() {
   config.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset) {
    dataset.data = dataset.data.map(function() {
     return randomScalingFactor();
    });
   });

   window.myPie.update();
  });

  var colorNames = Object.keys(window.chartColors);
  document.getElementById('addDataset').addEventListener('click', function() {
   var newDataset = {
    backgroundColor: [],
    data: [],
    label: 'New dataset ' + config.data.datasets.length,
   };

   for (var index = 0; index < config.data.labels.length; ++index) {
    newDataset.data.push(randomScalingFactor());

    var colorName = colorNames[index % colorNames.length];
    var newColor = window.chartColors[colorName];
    newDataset.backgroundColor.push(newColor);
   }

   config.data.datasets.push(newDataset);
   window.myPie.update();
  });

  document.getElementById('removeDataset').addEventListener('click', function() {
   config.data.datasets.splice(0, 1);
   window.myPie.update();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/utils.js"></script>
<body>
 <div id="canvas-holder" style="width:100%">
  <canvas id="chart-area"></canvas>
 </div>
 <button id="randomizeData">Randomize Data</button>
 <button id="addDataset">Add Dataset</button>
 <button id="removeDataset">Remove Dataset</button>
</body>
```

サンプルをスニペット以外で動作させると（私の表示環境ではスニペットでエラーを吐かないので、もしエラーを吐いていたらごめんなさい。）

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'red' of undefined

が表示されるのは、ボタン

```
<button id="randomizeData">Randomize Data</button>
<button id="addDataset">Add Dataset</button>
<button id="removeDataset">Remove Dataset</button>
```

が初期化（表示される前）前に

```
document.getElementById('xxxxxx')
```

を実行してしまっているためです。
`window.onload = function(){　}`で getElementByIdを 囲みオブジェクトが初期化された後にが動くようにするとエラーは出なくなります。

Comment: このコードは実行すると `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'red' of undefined` というエラーが出るようです。

Comment: スニペットで表示できる様に調整しているので、実際に動かす時は、chart.jsのぺーじからのサンプルを動かしてみて下さい。

Comment: パッと見る限り `chartColors` が定義されていないのだと思います。

Comment: yyzさま　お礼が遅れまして大変失礼しました。　直接、scriptの中に<?php echo $xxxx;  ?> というように書けばいいわけですね。jsonは敷居が高いのでphpでechoを吐き出して書くことにします。どうもお手数をお掛けしました。有難うございます。